# DataTable.Load, One or more rows contain values violating non-null, unique, or foreign-key constraints

Tags: c#, .net-4.0

I searched a lot, but could not find the solution.

I get the error:

> Failed to enable constraints. One or more rows contain values violating non-null, unique, or foreign-key constraints.

I run `DataTable.GetErrors()` and see that some columns are set to `Not NULL` in SQL Compact Edition Database. And these columns are used in `LEFT OUTER JOIN` query so they are null when the query is run. (I can get the results when i run the query in Server Explorer in VS).
The error occurs when trying to load the data in Datatable:

```
using (SqlCeCommand Cmd = new SqlCeCommand("Query HERE", "Connection HERE"))
                {
                    C.Open();
                    using (SqlCeDataReader Rdr = Cmd.ExecuteReader())
                    {
                        DataTable DT = new DataTable();
                        DT.Load(Rdr);
                        return DT;
                    }
                }
```

I tried so many solutions to overcome this however i was not able to solve it. I know about "EnforceConstraints" however as i do not use any dataset, i can not change that property.

Comment: I have seen this many times before typically with a DataSet populated by a query which returns two DataTables and the key is either NULL or does not join correctly between the two data tables.

Comment: There is only one datatable as you see from the code. And as i said, i do not use any datasets.

Comment: See my new answer at older thread https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7807681/getting-a-constraints-exception-when-loading-a-datareader-in-a-datatable/44533184#44533184 for a simple workaround that applies in at least some cases. This question probably qualifies as a duplicate of that thread, although there is valuable information in both.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Getting a constraints exception when loading a DataReader in a DataTable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7807681/getting-a-constraints-exception-when-loading-a-datareader-in-a-datatable)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I managed to solve this by getting the schema of the table, iterating through the rows of the schema table (which are columns of the actual table) and creating a column with same properties as the schema column (only difference is setting new column's AllowDBNull to true and Unique and AutoIncrement to false) and finally adding the new column to a fresh datatable which will later be filled with data of our actual table (by the help of a DataReader to get only data and not the schema).

Here is the code:

```
using (SqlCeConnection C = new SqlCeConnection(DBStr))
            using (Cmd)
            {   //using SqlCeCommand
                Cmd.Connection = C;
                C.Open();
                using (SqlCeDataReader Rdr = Cmd.ExecuteReader())
                {
                    //Create datatable to hold schema and data seperately
                    //Get schema of our actual table
                    DataTable DTSchema = Rdr.GetSchemaTable();
                    DataTable DT = new DataTable();
                    if (DTSchema != null)
                        if (DTSchema.Rows.Count > 0)
                            for (int i = 0; i < DTSchema.Rows.Count; i++)
                            {
                                //Create new column for each row in schema table
                                //Set properties that are causing errors and add it to our datatable
                                //Rows in schema table are filled with information of columns in our actual table
                                DataColumn Col = new DataColumn(DTSchema.Rows[i]["ColumnName"].ToString(), (Type)DTSchema.Rows[i]["DataType"]);
                                Col.AllowDBNull = true;
                                Col.Unique = false;
                                Col.AutoIncrement = false;
                                DT.Columns.Add(Col);
                            }

                    while (Rdr.Read())
                    {
                        //Read data and fill it to our datatable
                        DataRow Row = DT.NewRow();
                        for (int i = 0; i < DT.Columns.Count; i++)
                        {
                            Row[i] = Rdr[i];
                        }
                        DT.Rows.Add(Row);
                    }
                    //This is our datatable filled with data
                    return DT;
                }
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

In case it catches anyone else; in my SQLite database I had NULL entries stored as strings (`"NULL"`), simply fixing the data worked.

This is a SQLite specific issue as you can mix datatypes in columns!

Answer (score 0):

This can also happen if you load data from a table where some strings are only different in upper and lower case. In my case it happened using SQLite (Microsoft.Data.SQLite). I could fix it by setting `DataTable.CaseSensitive = true`. Code example in C#:

```
protected virtual DataTable Get(string sqlQuery)
{
    DataTable dataTable = new DataTable() { CaseSensitive = true };
    DbProviderFactory factory = SqliteFactory.Instance;
    using (DbConnection connection = GetConnection(factory))
    {
        using (DbCommand command = factory.CreateCommand())
        {
            command.Connection = connection;
            command.CommandText = sqlQuery;

            connection.Open();
            dataTable.Load(command.ExecuteReader());
        }
    }

    return dataTable;
}
```